# uiGridConstants undefined (but they are passed in to controller)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Trying to get an aggregation of the values of my column in uigrid.  I have injected `uiGridConstants` into the controller, and in my app.js i have `ui.grid`... However, regardless of what I do, `uiGridConstants` is being passed back as undefined. Anyone know?

GridOptions

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  infiniteScrollRowsFromEnd: '50',
  selectionRowHeaderWidth: '100',
  enableColumnMenus: false,
  rowHeight: '45',
  enableFiltering: true,
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'name', name: 'Name', width: '*', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a ui-sref="contacts-profile({ id: row.entity.id })">{{COL_FIELD}}</a></div>'},
    { field: 'type', name: 'Type', width: '*' },
    { field: 'status', name: 'Status', width: '*' },
    { field: 'premium', name: 'Premium', width: '*', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">${{COL_FIELD}}</div>', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.count },
    { field: 'commission', name: 'Comission', width: '*', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">${{COL_FIELD}}</div>' },
    { field: 'created_by', name: 'Created by', width: '*' }
  ]
};
```

Injector

```
constructor($scope, $location, CognitoService, $http, uiGridConstants, uiGridGroupingConstants) {

PoliciesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'CognitoService', '$http', '$q', '$timeout', '$filter', 'uiGridConstants', 'uiGridGroupingConstants'];
```

If I do a `console.log` of `uiGridConstants` I get

```
ƒ $Q(resolver) {
        if (!isFunction(resolver)) {
          throw $qMinErr('norslvr', 'Expected resolverFn, got \'{0}\'', resolver);
        }

        var promise = new Promise();

        function resolveFn(v…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
constructor($scope, $location, CognitoService, $http,  $q, $timeout, '$filter', uiGridConstants, uiGridGroupingConstants) {

PoliciesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'CognitoService', '$http', '$q', '$timeout', '$filter', 'uiGridConstants', 'uiGridGroupingConstants'];
```

The number of parameters must be the same and in the same order in the injection and in the constructor.